# SBT 0.13 taskKey macro doesn't work with [Unit]?

Tags: scala, sbt

```
lazy val buildDb = taskKey[Unit]("Initializes the database")

buildDb := {
  (compile in Compile).value
  val s: TaskStreams = streams.value
  s.log.info("Building database")
  try {
    ...
  } catch {
    case e: Throwable =>
      sys.error("Failed to initialize the database: " + e.getMessage)
  }
  s.log.info("Finished building database")
}
```

This produces the following error

```
C:\work\server\build.sbt:98: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: T
  s.log.info("Finished building database")
            ^
[error] Type error in expression
```

But if I define it like this `lazy val buildDb = taskKey[String]("Initializes the database")` and then add to the last line in the task `"Happy end!"` string everything seem to work. Am I to blame, or something wrong with the macro?

Comment: What happens if the last line is `()`.  I've used taskKey[Unit] before, so something seems very off here.

Comment: It works fine for me with SBT `0.13.2-M2`. Can you remove `try-catch` block and give it a shot again? Can you add `sbt about` to the question?

Comment: the try/catch block also caught my attention. I wonder if you might need to move that to its own method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same happened to me. I was able to fix the issue e.g. by adding a `: TaskKey[Unit]` to the taskKey definition. Here are my findings for sbt 0.13.5:

The following definition is OK (it seems that it is pure luck that this is OK):

```
lazy val collectJars = taskKey[Unit]("collects JARs")

collectJars := {
  println("these are my JARs:")
  (externalDependencyClasspath in Runtime).value foreach println
}
```

The following definition (the same as above without the first println) yields the same error "found: Unit, required: T":

```
lazy val collectJars = taskKey[Unit]("collects JARs")

collectJars := {
  (externalDependencyClasspath in Runtime).value foreach println
}
```

My findings are that **this is definitely something magical**: For example, if I indent the line `lazy val collectJars = ...` by one blank, then it compiles. I would expect (but have not checked) that .sbt and .scala build definitions also behave differently.

However, **if you add the type signature, it seems to always compile**:

```
lazy val collectJars: TaskKey[Unit] = taskKey[Unit]("collects JARs")

collectJars := {
  (externalDependencyClasspath in Runtime).value foreach println
}
```

Last but not least: The issue seems to be specific for TaskKey[Unit]. Unit tasks are not a good idea - in your example, you could at least return Boolean (true for success / false for failure).

Comment: I have a `TaskKey[Seq[File]]` task that also behaves strangely. At first I thought I had an error in my .sbt file, but then I realized adding a space to a string, or an extra line break also caused it throw a type mismatch error. Adding the type signature seems to have fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: It turns out that the type is irrelevant, that just caused sbt to flush data from a previous run that was causing the issue. It happened to me again even with the type signature. Deleting all my /target directories cleared it up.